# Add values in related list in test class

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, code-coverage, error

I have a custom object where I have a related list. 
I created a before insert before update trigger checking if there is any value in related list or not but when I try to write a test class for it and insert values in related list it gives following error message

> Field is not writeable:

Note: Activity is related list of dev plan object

```
 lmsilt__Activity__c act =new lmsilt__Activity__c();
    act.Name='Test_Activity';
    insert act;
    lmsilt__Development_Plan__c  devplan = new lmsilt__Development_Plan__c();
    devplan.Name='Mydev Plan';
    devplan.lmsilt__Activities__r=act;
    insert devplan;
```

> Error is shown for this line devplan.lmsilt__Activities__r=act;

Comment: Error indicates you are trying to put the value for read only field. you can not defined value for any read only field like `formula field`. check the line no. on which you getting error and make sure field is not ready only.

Comment: I am adding value to related list not a field. Let me update the question to include code in question.

Comment: Is the relationship here master-detail?

Comment: Is Act Master of DevPlan? If yes, I believe you are updating the wrong field. You should not use the relationship field for this.

Comment: No, they aren't directly related. I managed to do this by giving Dev Plan Id to Activity.  Like this                         
lmsilt__Development_Plan__c  devplan = new lmsilt__Development_Plan__c();
devplan.Name='Mydev Plan';
insert devplan;
lmsilt__Activity__c act =new lmsilt__Activity__c();
act.Name='Test_Activity';
act.lmsilt__Development_Plan__c=devplan.Id;
insert act;

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the problem is on this line:

```
devplan.lmsilt__Activities__r=act;
```

Try changing `__r` to `__c` and `act` to it's Id. For example:

```
devplan.lmsilt__Activities__c = act.Id;
```